# How can I add probability?

Tags: c++

it's my firt post here.

I have done this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int width = 60;
const int height = 20;

void generujpole(char pole[][height])
{
for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
{
for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
    {
    int maluj = rand()%2;
    if(maluj == 0) pole[i][j] = ' ';
    else pole[i][j] = 'o';
    }
}
}

void wypiszpole(char pole[][height])
{
cout << "+------------------------------------------------------------+"<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
    for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
    {
    cout << pole[i][j];
    }
cout << endl;
}
cout << "+------------------------------------------------------------+"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
char plansza[60][20];

generujpole(plansza);
wypiszpole(plansza);

return 0;
}
```

The language is polish, so don't be confused with the terminology.

I'm trying to make Conway's "Game of life", it's only the beginning for now, and
I do not really know what to do next. Right now, my problem is how to set a probability of drawing "o" to 15% vs 85% for blank space ""?

If it's possible, I just want to make a little change in my code, not doing something really ambitious and unknown, because probably I wouldn't understand it.

I hope there is someone who's willing to help me with this. :)

Comment: Probabilities relate to math, not to C++ programming. In C++, you could add apples and oranges, but that might not make any sense.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I get the impression you only read the title, not the question

Comment: But the title is *very* important. If you feel it is not related to the question, change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have basically got it already, except at the moment you are limiting yourself to 50% probability with the `%2` part.

Try increasing that to `% 100`, and instead of comparing the result with `== 0`, compare with `< 15`, which will occur approximately 15% of the time.

Comment: This is biased and doesn't provide 15/85.

Comment: Wow, it was this easy... Thanks. Is there any chance that you can also help me with another step with my program? What should I do, to for example create a new bacteria (o) when there are 3 (o) around the blank space?

Comment: @obeeey The comments section is not the place to ask a new question.  If you have a new question, as a new question.

Comment: Although since the answer is "assign the character literal `'o'` to the array element you're talking about", I'm not sure it's worth a whole question either. Give it a try and see, I guess.

Answer (score 8):

You should use the `random` header (`rand` is not advised):

```
#include <random>
```

And then in your function:

```
std::mt19937 rng;
rng.seed(std::random_device()());
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(0,99); // distribution in range [0, 100[

std::cout << dist(rng) << std::endl;
```

Then check if `dist(rng)` is lower than 15 to have your percentage.

Of course, the `dist` and the `rng` should be outside your `generujpole` function and be passed in.

Comment: Just curious. Why would `rand` be not advised?

Comment: @GillBates `rand` S****!.  It can be very non-random.

Comment: @GillBates The most common criticism I've encountered against `rand`is that there is no requirement on how good it's "randomness" has to be, and as a consequence many implementations are bad (and they are allowed to be). Additionally, the `rand() % x` approach can introduce a bias towards certain values, making it not quite uniform.

Comment: It's very weak, when it works, global state... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

Comment: STL gives an overview of why rand() is not good: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: Note that *fully* seeding a `mersenne_twister_engine` is actually tricky. It needs `state_size` values of `UIntType` of entropy to fully seed it. The approach shown here usually works fine, but the number of possible initial states is drastically less than what `mersenne_twister_engine` is capable of. In addition, every instance `std::random_device()` is allowed to return the same sequence every time. So on those platforms with non-random `std::random_device` this program has zero randomness and will always produce the exact same result on every execution.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now, my problem is how to set a probability of drawing "o" to
>   15% vs 85% for blank space ""?

Another possibility.  I like the following because this approach can easily show the distribution, and is easily modified.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::endl;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <algorithm>
using std::shuffle;

#include <random>   // random_device
using std::random_device, std::mt19937_64;



class T990_t
{
   vector<char>::size_type     sz100;
   vector<char>::size_type percent15;  // 15 percent
   vector<char>::size_type percent85;  // 85 percent
   vector<char> gameBoard;

public:
   T990_t() : sz100 (20*60) , percent15 (0) , percent85 (0), gameBoard()
      {
         gameBoard.reserve(sz100);
      }

   ~T990_t() = default;

   int operator()() { return exec(); }

private: // methods

   int exec()
      {
         // initialize the gameBoard to DEAD state
         for (vector<char>::size_type  i=0; i < sz100; ++i)
            gameBoard.push_back('~'); // DEAD state (using visible char)

         // how might we set 15% of gameboard to ALIVE?
         setGameBoardAlive ( 15U );

         showGameBoard (" at 15% (note poor (but valid) sequence) ");

         // how 'distribute' the 15% ?
         shuffleGameBoard();

         showGameBoard(" after shuffle ");

         return 0;
      }

   void setGameBoardAlive(vector<char>::size_type percentAlive)
      {
         percent15 = ( sz100 * percentAlive ) / 100;  // 15 percent
         percent85 = ( sz100 - percent15    );        // 85 percent

         cout << "\n  100 percent: " << setw(5) << sz100
              << "\n   15 percent: " << setw(5) << percent15
              << "\n   85 percent: " << setw(5) << percent85
              << "\n         sum : " << setw(5) << (percent15 + percent85)
              << endl;

         for (vector<char>::size_type i = 0; i < percent15; i++) {
            gameBoard[i] = 'o'; // ALIVE state
         }
      }

   void showGameBoard(string lbl)
      {
         int ll = 0;
         cout << "\n  GameBoard " << lbl << ": \n  ";
         for (vector<char>::size_type i=0; i<sz100; i++)
         {
            cout << gameBoard[i];
            ll += 1;
            if (ll > 100) { cout << "\n  "; ll = 0; }
         }
         cout << endl;
      }

   void shuffleGameBoard()
      {
         cout << "\n  gameBoard std::shuffle \n  ";
         random_device rd;
         mt19937_64 gen(rd());
         shuffle (gameBoard.begin(), gameBoard.end(), gen);
         //cout << "\n  ";
      }


}; // class T990_t


int main(int , char**) { return T990_t()(); }
```

With possible output:

```
  100 percent:  1200
   15 percent:   180
   85 percent:  1020
         sum :  1200

  GameBoard  at 15% (note poor (but valid) sequence) : 
  ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
  ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  gameBoard std::shuffle 

  GameBoard  after shuffle : 
  ~~o~~~~~o~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~o~o~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~o~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~o~o~~~~~o~~~~o~~o~~~~~~
  ~oo~~o~~oo~o~~~~~oo~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~o~~~~o~~~~o~o~oo~~~o~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~~o~~o
  ~~~~o~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~oo~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~o~~o~~~~~~~
  ~~~~~~o~~~oo~~~~o~~~o~~~~~o~~~~~o~~o~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~~~o~~o~o~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~
  ~o~~~~~~~~~~~~oo~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~o~o~~o~~~~~~~~~oo~~~~~oo~~~~o~~~~~~~~o~~o~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~o~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~o~~~~~o~~~~~oo~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~oooo~~~~~~~o~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~o~~~~
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~oo~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~o~oo~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~o~~~~~~~~o~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~
  ~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~o~o~~~o~~o~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~o~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~
  o~~~o~~~~~~~~~~o~o~~o~~~~~o~~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~o~~~~~~~o~~~~o~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~o~~~~~~~o~~~~~
  o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~oooo~~~o~~~~~~oo~~~~o~o~o~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~o~o~o~~~~~~~o~~~~~oo~~~~~~~~~~~~
  o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~oo~~~~~o~~~~o~~o~~~oo~~~~~oo~~~~o~o~~~o~~~o~~~o~~~~~o~~~~o~~~~~o~~~o~~~~~oo~~~~
  ~~~o~~~~oo~~~~~~~~~~oo~~~~~~o~~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o~~~~~~~~~~~~~~o
```