# How to distribute numbers by a certain percentage randomly within a matr

Tags: c++

I want to distribute numbers by a certain percentage randomly within a matrix.For example I have a matrix 150*150 and I want to Fill out with 0,1,2 
randomly with  percentage like this 10% for 0 30% for 2 and 60% for 1.What should I do.actually I did something but without percentage but it didn't work perfectly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 151 i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j <151; j++) {

        if (random(100) < 10) {

            Array(i, j) = 1;
        }

        if (random(50) < 10) {

            Array(i, j) = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add probability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395457/how-can-i-add-probability)

Comment: And more precisely my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395457/how-can-i-add-probability/53395552#53395552

Comment: You're almost there, buy you should only do `random(100)` **once** for each matrix element. Then check that value if it's below 10%, else if it's below 40% (10% + 30%), or else if it's below 100% (10% + 30% + 60%, you don't need to check this obviously).

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11, the Standard Library provides the function [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution), defined in header `<random>`, which

> produces random integers on the interval [0, n), where the probability of each individual integer i is defined as w
>   i/S, that is the weight of the ith integer divided by the sum of all n weights.

Given OP's percentages:

```
std::discrete_distribution<int> d({10, 60, 30});
```

[HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eaPX8NkFNTPrjjSQ), a testable code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that this is not the most efficient way to approach this problem and my beginner c++ code should never be used as it's, but still if you want a reference, this is how i did it :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 5

using tuple = std::tuple<int, int>;

const int Percentage(const int value)
{
  const int percent = std::round((value / 100.0) * (ROWS * COLS));
  std::cout << value << "% of " << ROWS * COLS << " : " << percent << std::endl;
  return percent;
}

const int RandomIndex(const int& size)
{
  std::mt19937 range;
  range.seed(std::random_device()());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(0, size);
  return dist(range);
}

void FillMatrix(int matr[][COLS], std::vector<tuple>& num)
{
  // holds the numbers, from which a random number
  // will be stored to the matrix
  std::vector<int> fillers;

  // holds the random index among the fillers
  uint8_t random_index;

  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
      /*
       * check if the count of a particular number to be added to
       * the matrix is zero or not.
       * if zero : then dont append to filler vector
       * else    : append to filler vector
       */
      for (tuple item : num) {
        if (std::get<1>(item) != 0) {
          fillers.emplace_back(std::get<0>(item));
        }
      }

      // get the index of a random item in fillers vector
      random_index = RandomIndex(fillers.size() - 1);

      // insert this random element to matrix
      matr[i][j] = fillers[random_index];

      /*
       * find the percentage value(or count) of the number
       * corresponding to the random number and decrement it
       * so as to denote that it has been used.
       */
      for (tuple& item : num) {
        if (std::get<0>(item) == fillers[random_index]) {
          std::get<1>(item) -= 1;
        }
      }

      // clear the current fillers vector
      fillers.clear();
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int matrix[ROWS][COLS];

  // each tuple has a number and it's corresponding percentage
  std::vector<tuple> numbers = {tuple(0, Percentage(10)),
                                tuple(1, Percentage(30)),
                                tuple(2, Percentage(60))};

  // fill the matrix with values provided in the vector
  FillMatrix(matrix, numbers);

  // print the matrix
  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
      std::cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**define ROWS and COLS as 150 in your case.**